# Count distinct in a rxSummary

Tags: group-by, distinct-values, revolution-r

I want to `count` distinct values of var2 grouping by var1 in a .xdf file,

I tried something like this

```
 myFun <- function(dataList) {
    UniqueLevel <<- unique(c(UniqueLevel, dataList$var2))
    SumUniqueLevel <<- length(UniqueLevel)
    return(NULL)
    }

rxSummary(formula = ~ var1,
data = "DefModelo2.xdf",
transformFunc = myFun,
transformObjects = list(UniqueLevel = NULL),
removeZeroCounts = F)
```

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

Probably using RevoPemaR is the the faster way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One other option is to use `rxCrossTabs`.  This way you get a cross-tabulation of the two factors, and you can just count non zero entries to determine unique values by one of the factors.

```
censusWorkers <- file.path(rxGetOption("sampleDataDir"), "CensusWorkers.xdf")
censusXtabAge <- rxCrossTabs(~ F(age):F(wkswork1), data = censusWorkers, 
                             removeZeroCounts = FALSE, returnXtabs = TRUE)
apply(censusXtabAge != 0, MARGIN = 1, sum)
```

Comment: This is a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Split by `var1`, and then for each group, count up the unique values of `var2`. This assumes that `var1` and `var2` are factors, if they're not you'll have to run `rxFactors` first.

```
xdflst <- rxSplit(xdf, splitByVars="var1", varsToKeep=c("var1", "var2"))

out <- rxExec(function(grp) {
        var1 <- head(grp, 1)$var1
        var2 <- rxDataStep(grp, varsToKeep="var2")$var2
        data.frame(var2, distinct=length(unique(var2)))
    },
    grp=rxElemArg(xdflst))

do.call(rbind, out)
```

Or you could get my [dplyrXdf package](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/dplyrXdf) and use a dplyr group_by/summarise pipeline (which basically does all the above, including converting to factors if necessary):

```
xdf %>% group_by(var1) %>%
    summarise(distinct=n_distinct(var2),
              .rxArgs=list(varsToKeep=c("var1", "var2")))
```