# SQL/SAS equivalent code in Microsoft-r

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I wanted to convert one of my Proc SQL/SAS code in Rev R/Microsoft-r

here is my sample code

```
proc sql;
create table GENDER_YEAR as
select YEAR,GENDER,count(distinct CARD_NO) as CM_COUNT,sum(SPEND) as TOTAL_SPEND, sum(case when SPEND GT 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NO_OF_TRANS
from ABC group by YEAR,GENDER;
quit;
```

I'm trying below code in Rev R

```
library("RevoPemaR")
byGroupPemaObj <- PemaByGroup()

GENDER_cv_grouped <- pemaCompute(pemaObj = byGroupPemaObj, data = Merchant_Trans,groupByVar = "GENDER",computeVars = c("LOCAL_SPEND"),fnList = list(sum = list(FUN = sum, x = NULL)))
```

it Calculate only on thing at a time, but i need Distinct Count of CARD_NO, SUM of SPEND, and No of no zero Rows for Spend as Trans for each segment of YEAR & Gender.

Output Should look like below

```
YEAR  GENDER CM_COUNT TOTAL_SPEND NO_OF_TRANS
YEAR1 M      23        120        119
YEAR1 F      21        110        110
YEAR2 M      20        121        121
YEAR2 F      35        111        109
```

Looking forward help on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Have you tried the package https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/dplyrXdf ? It has the exact same syntax as dplyr but works on XDF files. Also, why not concatenate both those columns into 1 column with a comma separation and group by that ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go about this it to concatenate the columns into a single column and use that. It seems that most both dplyrXdf and RevoPemaR do not support group by with 2 variables yet.

The way to do this would be by adding a [rxDataStep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt637394.aspx) on top which creates this variable first and then groups by it. Some approximate code for this is:

```
library("RevoPemaR")
byGroupPemaObj <- PemaByGroup()

rxDataStep(inData = Merchant_Trans, outFile = Merchant_Trans_Groups,
           transform = list(year_gender = paste(YEAR, GENDER,))

GENDER_cv_grouped <- pemaCompute(pemaObj = byGroupPemaObj,
    data = Merchant_Trans_Groups, groupByVar = "GENDER",
    computeVars = c("LOCAL_SPEND"),
    fnList = list(sum = list(FUN = sum, x = NULL)))
```

Note that overall there are 3 methods of doing a groupBy in RevR as far as I know. Each has it's pros and cons.

1. rxSplit - This actually creates different XDF files for each group that you want. This can be used with the `splitByFactor` arg where the factor specifies which groups should be created.
2. RevoPemaR's PemaByGroup - This assumes that each group's data can be stored in RAM. Which is a fair assumption. It also needs the original Xdf file to be sorted by the GroupBy column. And it only supports grouping by 1 column.
3. dplyrXdf's group_by - This is a spin on the popular dplyr package. It has many variable manipulation methods - so a different way to write rxSplit and rxDataStep) using dplyr like syntax. It also only supports 1 column to group with.

All three methods currently only support a single variable group operation. Hence they all require some pre processing of the data to work with.

Comment: Actually, dplyrXdf should work fine with multiple grouping variables (if it doesn't, please submit a bug report). The real issue here is that `count distinct` isn't a natively supported operation for xdf files and requires a [workaround.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328996/count-distinct-in-a-rxsummary)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using dplyrXdf. Unlike with data frames, the `n_distinct()` summary function provided by dplyr doesn't work with xdf files, so this does a two-step summarisation: first including `card_no` as a grouping variable, and then count the number of `card_no`'s.

First, generate some example data:

```
library(dplyrXdf)     # also loads dplyr
set.seed(12345)

df <- expand.grid(year=2000:2005, gender=c("F", "M")) %>%
    group_by(year, gender) %>%
    do(data.frame(card_no=sample(20, size=10, replace=TRUE),
                  spend=rbinom(10, 1, 0.5) * runif(10) * 100))

xdf <- rxDataStep(df, "ndistinct.xdf", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Now call `summarise` twice, taking advantage of the fact that the first `summarise` will remove `card_no` from the list of grouping variables:

```
smry <- xdf %>%
    mutate(trans=spend > 0) %>%
    group_by(year, gender, card_no) %>%
    summarise(n=n(), total_spend=sum(spend), no_of_trans=sum(trans)) %>%
    summarise(cm_count=n(), total_spend=sum(total_spend), no_of_trans=sum(no_of_trans))

as.data.frame(smry)    

   #year gender cm_count total_spend no_of_trans
#1  2000      F       10   359.30313           6
#2  2001      F        8   225.89571           3
#3  2002      F        7   332.58365           6
#4  2003      F        5   333.72169           5
#5  2004      F        7   280.90448           5
#6  2005      F        9   254.37680           5
#7  2000      M        8   309.77727           6
#8  2001      M        8   143.70835           2
#9  2002      M        8   269.64968           5
#10 2003      M        8   265.27049           4
#11 2004      M        9    99.73945           3
#12 2005      M        8   178.12686           6
```

Verify that this is the same result (modulo row ordering) as you'd get by running a dplyr chain on the original data frame:

```
df %>%
    group_by(year, gender) %>%
    summarise(cm_count=n_distinct(card_no), total_spend=sum(spend), no_of_trans=sum(spend > 0)) %>%
    arrange(gender, year)

    #year gender cm_count total_spend no_of_trans
   #<int> <fctr>    <int>       <dbl>       <int>
#1   2000      F       10   359.30313           6
#2   2001      F        8   225.89571           3
#3   2002      F        7   332.58365           6
#4   2003      F        5   333.72169           5
#5   2004      F        7   280.90448           5
#6   2005      F        9   254.37680           5
#7   2000      M        8   309.77727           6
#8   2001      M        8   143.70835           2
#9   2002      M        8   269.64968           5
#10  2003      M        8   265.27049           4
#11  2004      M        9    99.73945           3
#12  2005      M        8   178.12686           6
```